Keras datasets load issue
I have a problem with keras dataset imports. When I try to use
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import mnist

It says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.datasets'
I reinstalled keras and TF withoutr success. I tried below command in VSCode:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist; (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(); print(x_train.shape);"

and I received below response :
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz
11490434/11490434 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 0us/step 
(60000, 28, 28)

So it connected to the repo and showed shape of the array. I downloaded this npz file, created directory called datasets and placed this file into it and now error message is like that:
ImportError: cannot import name 'mnist' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.datasets' (unknown location).

I tried to load file with np.load('C:\path') but this ended with the following error:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Please help me with fixing that.

This question is similar to: Error "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I managed to solve that. Below code worked but when I moved file to other directory, it does not work within keras/datasets/...
path = 'C:\ML\Deep Learning\mnist.npz'  #full path to the dataset

with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True) as f:
  x_train, y_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
  x_test, y_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']

Regards
Piotr

This works in your case, but it's lucky - if your folders had different names, it wouldn't work anymore. For example if you moved the file to "C:\Users\ML\Deep Learning\mnist.npz", you would end up with the same error as above.
